# How to use getline to delimit by comma *and* <space> in c++?

Tags: c++

chicken, for sale, 60

microwave, wanted, 201.

These are examples lines from my txt file. Right now this is my code:

```
while(getline(data, word, '\n')){
    ss<<word;

    while(getline(ss, word, ',')){//prints entire file
        cout<<word<<endl;
    }
}
```

and my output is:

```
chicken
 for sale
 60
```

My file is succesfully parsed line by line, but I also need to get rid of that space after each comma. Adding a space after the comma here just gives me an error "no matching function to call 'getline(...:

```
 while(getline(ss, word, ', '))
```

SOLUTION: I just used the erase function

```
 if(word[0]==' '){//eliminates space
        word.erase(0,1);
    }
```

Comment: std::getline can only take  a single separator - you need to process what you read further with something like std::substr

Comment: `std::getline` is a simple parsing function that offers the option of specifying a single delimiter character.

When your parsing requirements are a bit more complex, you must implement your parsing algorithm by yourself.

Your approach is on the right track: break up the input into comma-separated chunks. Now, take each chunk, as a string, and remove the beginning, and perhaps the trailing whitespace. You should be able to find examples of how to do so in your C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

getline just parses single parameter.
If you want to parse the multiple delimiters, You can use boost library.

```
std::string delimiters("|,:-;");
std::vector<std::string> parts;
boost::split(parts, inputString, boost::is_any_of(delimiters));
for(int i = 0; i<parts.size();i++ ) {
    std::cout <<parts[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::ws` to get rid of any leading whitespace of each part:

```
while(getline(ss >> std::ws, word, ','))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
std::string line;
std::string tok;
while (std::getline(data, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (std::getline(iss >> std::ws, tok, ',')) {
        tok.erase(tok.find_last_not_of(" \t\r\n") + 1);
        std::cout << tok << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/OpY50Q)

You can then wrap the above logic in a custom overloaded `>>` operator:

```
class token : public std::string {};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, token &out)
{
    out.clear();
    if (std::getline(in >> std::ws, out, ','))
        out.erase(out.find_last_not_of(" \t\r\n") + 1);
    return in;
}
```

```
std::string line;
token tok;
while (std::getline(data, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (iss >> tok) {
        std::cout << tok << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/higGVY)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I just used the erase function

```
if(word[0]==' '){//eliminates space
    word.erase(0,1);
}
```